# switch/case always returns default value

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem: my function always returns the default value, no matter what I try. When I use if/else statements everything works fine. Where is the failure?

```js
function auswertung(stueckzahl) {

 var preis1 = 0.77;
 var preis2 = 0.76;
 var preis3 = 0.73;
 var preis4 = 0.69;
 var preis5 = 0.67;

  switch(stueckzahl) {
   
  case ((stueckzahl>=500) && (stueckzahl <= 1000)): {
   return preis1;
  }
  case ((stueckzahl >= 1001) && (stueckzahl <= 2500)): {
   return preis2;
  }
  case ((stueckzahl >= 2501) && (stueckzahl <= 5000)): {
   return preis3;
  }
  case ((stueckzahl >= 5001) && (stueckzahl <= 10000)): {
   return preis4;
  }
  case ((stueckzahl >= 10001) && (stueckzahl <= 30000)): {
   return preis5;
  }
  default: {
   return preis1;
  }

  }
 }
  
document.write (auswertung(10000));
```

Comment: `(stueckzahl>=500) && (stueckzahl <= 1000)` will evaluate to either true or false

Comment: You need either `switch (true)` or an if-else chain.

Comment: `switch` compares the value of the switched variable `stueckzahl` with each of the `case` statements.  Since `stueckzahl` is never equal to `true` or `false` you're getting the `default` block every time.  You're not using `switch` correctly.

Answer (score 8):

You can perfectly use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) with a boolean `true` as [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) to re-evaluate your cases one by one.

This way your code stays clean:

```js
function auswertung(stueckzahl) {
  switch (true) {
    case stueckzahl >= 10001 && stueckzahl <= 30000:
      return 0.67;
    case stueckzahl >= 5001 && stueckzahl <= 10000:
      return 0.69;
    case stueckzahl >= 2501 && stueckzahl <= 5000:
      return 0.73;
    case stueckzahl >= 1001 && stueckzahl <= 2500:
      return 0.76;
    case stueckzahl >= 500 && stueckzahl <= 1000:
    default:
      return 0.77;
  }
}

console.log('500:', auswertung(500));
console.log('10000:', auswertung(10000));
console.log('30000:', auswertung(30000));
```

Comment: +1 but for what it's worth I find that using `switch` this way is misleading.  IMHO it's better to just use `if..else` instead.

Comment: @Yuck it can be done in many different ways. But, for this specific situations the switch statement shines. The `auswertung()` function re-evaluate `expressions` one by one and returns  the proper "preis" at the first `true` case.. Just clean;)

Comment: @Yuck also one of the advantages of using `switch` is specifically to avoid the use of multiple `if () {...} else if () {...}` statements

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing an expression to the `case` statement then it is evaluated first.

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-switch-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

> 1. Let exprRef be the result of evaluating Expression.
> 2. Let switchValue be GetValue(exprRef).

So,

```
(stueckzahl>=500) && (stueckzahl <= 1000)
```

will be either `true` or `false`.

Which means unless `stueckzahl` is `true/false`, it will always go to `default` section.

You need to replace this `switch` statements with `if/else` by doing. (also just check the upper limit in every condition)

```
    if ( stueckzahl <= 1000) {
        return preis1;
    }
    if ( stueckzahl <= 2500 ) {
        return preis2;
    }
    if ( stueckzahl <= 5000 ) {
        return preis3;
    }
    if ( stueckzahl <= 10000 ) {
        return preis4;
    }
    if ( stueckzahl <= 30000 ) {
        return preis5;
    }
    else {
        return preis1;
    }
```

Comment: After the first `if` statement the OP doesn't really need to compare the low end value anymore either.  It can just compare the upper limit of each value segment.

Comment: @Yuck thats a good suggestion, thanks. I have made the changes

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `break;` after each `case` statement.

**e.g.**

```
switch (true) {
    case ((stueckzahl >= 500) && (stueckzahl <= 1000)): return preis1; break;
    case ((stueckzahl >= 1001) && (stueckzahl <= 2500)): return preis2; break;
    [...]
}
```

Otherwise the script will go on to check the next `case`.

Without `break;`, the script will always finish by running the `default case`.

Comment: You don't need to use break if you are doing return. he is using completely wrong the switch statement

Answer (score 0):

Your switch expects "stueckzahl" to be a value, not "true" or "false", and that is what "(stueckzahl>=500) && (stueckzahl <= 1000)" returns.

**You have to use "if/else" statements in order to achieve what you want**

Comment: Thank you all, your answers helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The way switch works is the follwoing.

Switch expression is compared to the the different case values. And the code under a case is executed if that comparison evaluates true.

Your switch expression is `stueckzahl`

One of the case expressions values is: `((stueckzahl>=500) && (stueckzahl <= 1000))` which will evaluate to true or false depending on the value of stueckzahl.

So at the end what you will be comparing is: `stueckzahl == true` or `stueckzahl == false` which will never be true if you pass numbers as parameters for your function.

In your case looks that what you want is a chain of ifs:

```
    if ((stueckzahl>=500) && (stueckzahl <= 1000)) {
        return preis1;
    }
    if ((stueckzahl >= 1001) && (stueckzahl <= 2500)) {
        return preis2;
    }
    if ((stueckzahl >= 2501) && (stueckzahl <= 5000)) {
        return preis3;
    }
    if ((stueckzahl >= 5001) && (stueckzahl <= 10000)) {
        return preis4;
    }
    if ((stueckzahl >= 10001) && (stueckzahl <= 30000)) {
        return preis5;
    }

    return preis1;
```

More details in: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp